# React webpack error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm currently in the process of learning React and have encountered an error in the webpack section. I use the plugin transform-class-properties for the arrow functions but webpack shows error in processing them.

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js 86:20
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (86:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         }
|     }
>     handleRemoveAll = () => {
|         this.setState( () => ({ options: [] }));
|     }
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

my webpack config file looks like this

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
};
```

and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Test User",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "build-babel": "babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=react,env --plugins=transform-class-properties --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a loader to webpack configuration

https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/javascript/

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
```

Also a `.babelrc` file

```
{
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          browsers: 'last 2 versions',
        },
        loose: true,
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: ['transform-class-properties'],
}
```